# PHP DOM Parsing and mysql Error

Tags: php, mysql, parsing, dom

i am referring to answer to my question , answer was provided by @abhy, that worked, the link is [php proDOM parsing error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8870519/php-prodom-parsing-error)

i am further working on it and want to save the extracted data into mysql database...

the code i am using is

```
 ?php
$ch = curl_init(); // create a new cURL resource
$word = 'books';
// set URL and other appropriate options
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://images.google.com/images?q=".$word."s&tbm=isch/");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);

$data = curl_exec($ch); // grab URL and pass it to the browser
curl_close($ch); 

$dom = new DOMDocument();
@$dom->loadHTML($data); // avoid warnings

$listA = $dom->getElementsByTagName('a'); // read all <a> elements
foreach ($listA as $itemA) { // loop through each <a> element
    if ($itemA->hasAttribute('href')) { // check if it has an 'href' attribute
        $href = $itemA->getAttribute('href'); // read the value of 'href'
        if (preg_match('/^\/imgres\?/', $href)) { // check that 'href' should begin with "/imgres?"
            $qryString = substr($href, strpos($href, '?') + 1);
            parse_str($qryString, $arrHref); // read the query parameters from 'href' URI
        echo '<br>' . $arrHref['imgurl'] . '<br>';
    $sql = "INSERT INTO `p_url_imgsrch`(`id`, `word_id`, `url_imgsrch`) VALUES ('','8','$arrHref['imgurl']')";

    mysql_query($sql) or die("error in updating urls") ;

        }
    }
}


?>
```

the idea is, i will insert each link in database, extracted from parsing, i am sure that my connection is okay, the same mysql query string with dummy data is working in mysql and inserting data successfully. however i use dummy url in place of  `'$arrHref['imgurl']'`..

the error i get is

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE,
>   expecting T_STRING or T_VARIABLE or T_NUM_STRING in
>   D:\wamp\www\demo\login\abhay.php on line 24

abhay.php is the file having this code, also, when trying to resolve the issue, sometime error was something like T_STRING ...

where i am doing the blunder? kindly give me a guideline..

thanks

Comment: Your code could be much simpler: use `DOMDocument->loadHtmlFile()` over cURL, use `libxml_use_internal_errors` over suppressing errors with `@`, use `DOMXPath->query` with `//a[@href(starts-with(., "/imgres"))]` instead of regex.

Comment: thanks @Gordon , i saw many useful answers provided by you, thanks for all of them, however, i am totally a new bee , trying to learn things, i am trying to grab what you are saying, but at the moment, i am not getting them all, please give me some more guideline..

Comment: sorry, the xpath should read `//a/@href[starts-with(., "/imgres")]`

Comment: working example: http://codepad.viper-7.com/Cdk7SF

Comment: thanks @Gordon trying to learn it...thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `"{$arrHref['imgurl']}"` so php knows that this is a variable
and you should not insert `id` if you want it to be auto incremented:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO `p_url_imgsrch`(`word_id`, `url_imgsrch`) VALUES ('8','{$arrHref['imgurl']}')";
```

However this might cause a corrupt sql command as soon as $arrHref['imgurl'] contains a single quote.

So a better solution would be to use `mysql_real_escape_string`:

```
$imgurl = mysql_real_escape_string($arrHref['imgurl']);

$sql = "INSERT INTO `p_url_imgsrch`(`word_id`, `url_imgsrch`) VALUES ('8','{$imgurl}')";
```

Comment: and can you lease tell me the error i was doing? also, can i use an array here which will store only 10 items in database??

Comment: You can easily debug your error by adding `echo $sql;` before you execute it.

Comment: thanks for guideline dear, echo $sql will help me in learning things, thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO `p_url_imgsrch`(`id`, `word_id`, `url_imgsrch`) VALUES ('','8','$arrHref[imgurl]')";
```

Be aware that this could lead to harming code getting injected.

Comment: thanks @OptimusCrime , how to avoid code injection in sql for this specific query? any guideline please..